# Is there any situation where a person who admitted to breaking the law in the interest of the United States can not be convicted legally?

Tags: united-states, law, impeachment, war-crime

For example when the bombs were dropped on Japan which killed innocent civilians, but the people in the military responsible for it was not punished seemingly because ending the war was believed to be in the public interest. Is this in law or did no one decide to try to jail them because they were ok with what was clearly a war crime.

I am referring to United States law.

Comment: Besides the obvious answer that wars are rarely guided by morality or intentional treaties, the Fourth Geneva Convention on the Treatment of Civilians in War was not signed until 1949. The previous ones dealt with the treatment of wounded soldiers and prisoners of war. The Hague conventions did talk about targeting civilians, but all they said was that "the attack or bombardment of towns, villages, habitations or buildings
which are not defended, is prohibited," so that targeting primarily civilians in defended zones was not prohibited.

Comment: The Geneva protocol banned gas attacks as well, but not targeting cities indiscriminately. So in fact, at the time the USA may not have been part of any international treaty that classified itd actions as war crimes, and I doubt that its laws were more forward-thinking.

Comment: The fact that the victors were not held liable for war crimes for the firebombing of Dresden and Tokyo and the attacks on Hiroshima and Nagasaki probably does not indicate anything one way or another, but for instance, I do not think the German army was formally accused of war crimes for the Blitz. It seems that as long as the bombing took out military targets, enormous civilian casualties may have been accepted by international law at that time.

Comment: You need to further clarify what you mean here. Something can be a crime in one country but not in another. Spying for one's country (in the territory of another) for instance falls into that category. You've tagged with with a bunch of things from impeachment to war crimes, so it's unclear what domains you're thinking of (besides the example you gave). For impeachment is quite debatable whether only strict criminal standards apply.

Comment: I am referring to United States law.

Comment: By definition, if something is allowed by law it's not a crime under that jurisdiction. So your q is basically "legal nonsense".

Comment: I mean that they would let it go even though it is illegal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your new title q

> Is there any situation where a person who admitted to breaking the law in the interest of the United States can not be convicted legally?

(which doesn't have anything to do with the body anymore) the answer is that they (probably) cannot be legally convicted if they have already been pardoned, which can happen before conviction or even before (hypothetical) prosecution. Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_pardons_in_the_United_States):

> A federal pardon can be issued prior to the start of a legal case or inquiry, prior to any indictments being issued, for unspecified offenses, and prior to or after a conviction for a federal crime. Ford's broad federal pardon of former president Richard M. Nixon in 1974 for "all offenses against the United States which he, Richard Nixon, has committed or may have committed or taken part in during the period from January 20, 1969 through August 9, 1974" is a notable example of a fixed-period federal pardon that came prior to any indictments being issued and that covered unspecified federal offenses that may or may not have been committed. [...]
>
> The constitutionality of open pardons, such as Ford's pardon of Nixon, has never been judicially tested in the Supreme Court and is open to question.

Also, if they died before the trial ends.

Basically "admitted to breaking the [US] law in the interest of the United States" is not a category that has enjoyed protection in precedents I know of.

If you really want to talk of the divergence between some international law, e.g. that that the [ICC tries to enforce and US vision on the same issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_and_the_International_Criminal_Court), that's a different matter.

Comment: Additional cases even without the interest of the United States red herring:
(a) statute of limitations and
(b) ne bis in idem